# 2009 Jaguar xf 2.7 diesel battery issues

Tags: electrical, battery, jaguar

Car wouldnt start this morning and battery reading 11.66 v on the multimeter so time for a change I think.Looked to see the age of the battery and found this inscribed on the top of the battery....surely not 1979?

The number is
`H3C110303 0379`
`586330`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Considering the Jag is a 2009 model, might be the battery is also? (I can't see the image at work, so can't see the date code you're talking about).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I added the number as text.

Comment: What brand of battery is it?

Comment: Are you sure you are reading it correctly? - See https://www.odysseybattery.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/Battery-Date-Codes-and-Serial-Numbers-010521.pdf

Comment: If that is the actual date code for the battery, the "C" would indicate this battery was produced in 2017. I'm not *sure* this is the actual code you should be looking at thought.